# Static linking ActiveMQ-cpp

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, static-libraries, activemq-cpp

I am creating a c++ project where I want it to run in standalone mode without any dependencies since it will be deployed on multiple servers.

This is my **CMakeLists** file :

```
project(CMS-test)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

add_executable(main main.cpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/usr/local/apr/include/apr-1)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/usr/local/include/activemq-cpp-3.9.4)

target_link_libraries(main ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libapr-1.a)
target_link_libraries(main ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libactivemq-cpp.a)
```

> libactivemq-cpp.a and libapr-1.a are found in my project directory

but the error I'm getting after `make main` during linking is

```
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/DecafRuntime.cpp:72: undefined reference to `apr_initialize'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/DecafRuntime.cpp:73: undefined reference to `apr_pool_create_ex'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-DecafRuntime.o): In function `decaf::lang::Runtime::shutdownRuntime()':
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/DecafRuntime.cpp:109: undefined reference to `apr_pool_destroy'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/DecafRuntime.cpp:110: undefined reference to `apr_terminate'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-Network.o): In function `decaf::internal::net::Network::initializeNetworking()':
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/Network.cpp:116: undefined reference to `apr_signal_block'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-SecureRandomImpl.o): In function `decaf::internal::security::SecureRandomImpl::providerNextBytes(unsigned char*, int)':
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/security/unix/SecureRandomImpl.cpp:128: undefined reference to `apr_file_read_full'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-SecureRandomImpl.o): In function `decaf::internal::security::SecureRandomImpl::SecureRandomImpl()':
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/security/unix/SecureRandomImpl.cpp:76: undefined reference to `apr_file_open'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-Exception.o): In function `decaf::lang::Exception::buildMessage(char const*, __va_list_tag (&) [1])':
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/lang/Exception.cpp:124: undefined reference to `apr_pvsprintf'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-System.o): In function `decaf::lang::System::unsetenv(std::string const&)':
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/lang/System.cpp:276: undefined reference to `apr_env_delete'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/lang/System.cpp:286: undefined reference to `apr_strerror'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-System.o): In function `decaf::lang::System::getenv(std::string const&)':
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/lang/System.cpp:297: undefined reference to `apr_env_get'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/lang/System.cpp:306: undefined reference to `apr_strerror'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-System.o): In function `decaf::lang::System::setenv(std::string const&, std::string const&)':
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/lang/System.cpp:326: undefined reference to `apr_env_set'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/lang/System.cpp:336: undefined reference to `apr_strerror'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-InetAddress.o): In function `decaf::net::InetAddress::getLocalHost()':
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/net/InetAddress.cpp:158: undefined reference to `apr_gethostname'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/net/InetAddress.cpp:168: undefined reference to `apr_sockaddr_info_get'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-AprPool.o): In function `decaf::internal::AprPool::destroyPool()':
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/AprPool.cpp:50: undefined reference to `apr_pool_destroy'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-AprPool.o): In function `decaf::internal::AprPool::allocatePool() const':
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/AprPool.cpp:42: undefined reference to `apr_pool_create_unmanaged_ex'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-AprPool.o): In function `decaf::internal::AprPool::cleanup()':
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/AprPool.cpp:60: undefined reference to `apr_pool_clear'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-TcpSocket.o): In function `decaf::internal::net::tcp::TcpSocket::connect(std::string const&, int, int)':
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/tcp/TcpSocket.cpp:312: undefined reference to `apr_sockaddr_info_get'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/tcp/TcpSocket.cpp:318: undefined reference to `apr_socket_opt_get'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/tcp/TcpSocket.cpp:319: undefined reference to `apr_socket_timeout_get'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/tcp/TcpSocket.cpp:322: undefined reference to `apr_socket_opt_set'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/tcp/TcpSocket.cpp:328: undefined reference to `apr_socket_timeout_set'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/tcp/TcpSocket.cpp:332: undefined reference to `apr_socket_connect'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/tcp/TcpSocket.cpp:335: undefined reference to `apr_socket_opt_set'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/tcp/TcpSocket.cpp:336: undefined reference to `apr_socket_timeout_set'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/tcp/TcpSocket.cpp:326: undefined reference to `apr_socket_timeout_set'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-TcpSocket.o): In function `decaf::internal::net::tcp::TcpSocket::available()':
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/tcp/TcpSocket.cpp:417: undefined reference to `apr_os_sock_get'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-TcpSocket.o): In function `decaf::internal::net::tcp::TcpSocket::getLocalAddress() const':
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/tcp/TcpSocket.cpp:376: undefined reference to `apr_socket_addr_get'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/tcp/TcpSocket.cpp:378: undefined reference to `apr_sockaddr_ip_getbuf'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-TcpSocket.o): In function `decaf::internal::net::tcp::TcpSocket::getOption(int) const':
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/tcp/TcpSocket.cpp:571: undefined reference to `apr_socket_opt_get'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/tcp/TcpSocket.cpp:541: undefined reference to `apr_socket_timeout_get'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/tcp/TcpSocket.cpp:545: undefined reference to `apr_socket_opt_get'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-TcpSocket.o): In function `decaf::internal::net::tcp::TcpSocket::setOption(int, int)':
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/tcp/TcpSocket.cpp:621: undefined reference to `apr_socket_opt_set'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/tcp/TcpSocket.cpp:591: undefined reference to `apr_socket_opt_set'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/tcp/TcpSocket.cpp:593: undefined reference to `apr_socket_timeout_set'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/tcp/TcpSocket.cpp:603: undefined reference to `apr_socket_opt_set'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-TcpSocket.o): In function `decaf::internal::net::tcp::TcpSocket::read(unsigned char*, int, int, int)':
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/tcp/TcpSocket.cpp:675: undefined reference to `apr_socket_recv'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-TcpSocket.o): In function `decaf::internal::net::tcp::TcpSocket::write(unsigned char const*, int, int, int)':
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/tcp/TcpSocket.cpp:745: undefined reference to `apr_socket_send'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-TcpSocket.o): In function `decaf::internal::net::tcp::TcpSocket::create()':
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/tcp/TcpSocket.cpp:157: undefined reference to `apr_socket_create'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/tcp/TcpSocket.cpp:161: undefined reference to `apr_os_sock_get'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-TcpSocket.o): In function `decaf::internal::net::tcp::TcpSocket::accept(decaf::net::SocketImpl*)':

/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/net/SocketError.cpp:42: undefined reference to `apr_strerror'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-Date.o): In function `decaf::util::Date::toString() const':
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/util/Date.cpp:112: undefined reference to `apr_time_exp_lt'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/util/Date.cpp:117: undefined reference to `apr_strftime'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-OpenSSLContextSpi.o): In function `decaf::internal::net::ssl::openssl::OpenSSLContextSpi::providerInit(decaf::security::SecureRandom*)':
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/ssl/openssl/OpenSSLContextSpi.cpp:188: undefined reference to `SSL_load_error_strings'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/ssl/openssl/OpenSSLContextSpi.cpp:189: undefined reference to `SSL_library_init'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/ssl/openssl/OpenSSLContextSpi.cpp:190: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/ssl/openssl/OpenSSLContextSpi.cpp:226: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/ssl/openssl/OpenSSLContextSpi.cpp:245: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/ssl/openssl/OpenSSLContextSpi.cpp:253: undefined reference to `RAND_seed'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-OpenSSLContextSpi.o): In function `decaf::internal::net::ssl::openssl::OpenSSLContextSpi::~OpenSSLContextSpi()':
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/ssl/openssl/OpenSSLContextSpi.cpp:162: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_set_locking_callback'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/ssl/openssl/OpenSSLContextSpi.cpp:163: undefined reference to `EVP_cleanup'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-OpenSSLContextSpi.o): In function `~ContextData':
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/ssl/openssl/OpenSSLContextSpi.cpp:110: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_free'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-OpenSSLSocketException.o): In function `decaf::internal::net::ssl::openssl::OpenSSLSocketException::getErrorString() const':
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/ssl/openssl/OpenSSLSocketException.cpp:102: undefined reference to `ERR_get_error'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/ssl/openssl/OpenSSLSocketException.cpp:104: undefined reference to `ERR_error_string_n'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/ssl/openssl/OpenSSLSocketException.cpp:102: undefined reference to `ERR_get_error'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-OpenSSLParameters.o): In function `decaf::internal::net::ssl::openssl::OpenSSLParameters::OpenSSLParameters(ssl_ctx_st*)':
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/ssl/openssl/OpenSSLSocket.cpp:573: undefined reference to `SSL_write'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/ssl/openssl/OpenSSLSocket.cpp:575: undefined reference to `SSL_get_error'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-OpenSSLSocket.o): In function `decaf::internal::net::ssl::openssl::OpenSSLSocket::available()':
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/ssl/openssl/OpenSSLSocket.cpp:641: undefined reference to `X509_free'
libactivemq-cpp.a(libactivemq_cpp_la-OpenSSLSocket.o): In function `decaf::internal::net::ssl::openssl::OpenSSLSocket::verifyServerCert(std::string const&)':
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/ssl/openssl/OpenSSLSocket.cpp:686: undefined reference to `X509_get_subject_name'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/ssl/openssl/OpenSSLSocket.cpp:692: undefined reference to `X509_NAME_get_index_by_NID'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/ssl/openssl/OpenSSLSocket.cpp:367: undefined reference to `SSL_ctrl'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/ssl/openssl/OpenSSLSocket.cpp:370: undefined reference to `SSL_connect'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/ssl/openssl/OpenSSLSocket.cpp:376: undefined reference to `SSL_get_error'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/ssl/openssl/OpenSSLSocket.cpp:406: undefined reference to `SSL_set_verify'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/ssl/openssl/OpenSSLSocket.cpp:408: undefined reference to `SSL_accept'
/home/isammour/Desktop/smart/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4/src/main/decaf/internal/net/ssl/openssl/OpenSSLSocket.cpp:361: undefined reference to `SSL_set_verify'
```

and more..

I don't know what to do to fix these errors

Any advice ?

Comment: For the `pthread` functions, use the [`FindThreads`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindThreads.html) module.

Comment: Ok pthread errors are gone, what about the others ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that I was doing  the `target_link_libraries` in the wrong order and as pointed by [Finn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50026197/9696886) I changed the order of the libraries

The full working `CMakeLists` file now is

```
project(CMS-test C CXX)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

add_executable(main main.cpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/usr/local/apr/include/apr-1)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/usr/local/include/activemq-cpp-3.9.4)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/)
find_package (Threads)
target_link_libraries(main ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})


target_link_libraries(main ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libactivemq-cpp.a)
target_link_libraries(main ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libapr-1.a)
target_link_libraries(main ssl)
target_link_libraries(main crypto)
target_link_libraries(main dl)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume apr is a dependency of activemq. If this is the case, you need to switch the link order of apr and activemq.

The linker will only use each library once. And when it processes libactivemq-cpp.a it sees that it depends on apr, but libapr-1.a has already been processed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it pointed me for what i was doing wrong, I'll post the full fix.